# Java mesageSource best practice

Tags: java, string, spring, properties, vaadin

I'm creating a vaadin view class wрich has the messages in properties which is the expected, and I'm using those values to set the labels messages, buttons, etc.
I know that a good practice should be to have each value in a private String:

```
private static String BUTTON_LABEL = "view.form.button";
```

...

```
messageSource.getMessage("BUTTON_LABEL");
```

The thing is I have a form with like 20 fields, should I create ~ 20 of those fields even if I know that I will just use then once? Am I violating a good practice if I call the messageSource in the methods instead of using the constant values?

Comment: i don't think this is actually working with a language switch and multiple instances running?  why not put just your constant there?  ``private static final String BUTTON_LABEL = "view.form.button"`` and then pull it through your i18n when creating the form/fields.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, corrected example.

Comment: ``messageSource.getMessage(BUTTON_LABEL)`` btw; if your IDE is not helping with the strings used for the i18n you are most likely depending on writing fire-and-forget strings anyway.  you could as well use a constant prefix (``view.form.``) and then compose the actual message code from the const and a "postfix" (``button``).